# How to create LIFO executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I would like to create a thread pool which will execute the most recently submitted task.  Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could probably just implement your own [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) wrapper that maps offer/poll to a stack.  Then use this as the `BlockingQueue` implementation you pass to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  My suggestion would be to wrap one of the existing `Deque` implementations such as [`ArrayDeque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

- This is not synchronized, so you'll need to wrap each of the `BlockingQueue` methods with a synchronizer (if not something more exotic).
- You'll also need to introduce `wait`/`notify` conditions for the blocking operations.
- Finally, you'll need to map one set of the `BlockingQueue` polarities (either the "put" or the "take" side) to the same end of the dequeue as the other (to treat it like a stack).

Note that there is some work (see Herlihy's book on *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*) on faster concurrent stacks, but I don't think there are any implementations in the JDK and I'm not sure if Herlihy's implementations offer blocking flavors.

### An Implementation atop Deque

I checked the [Android documentation, which suggests that Deque is around](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) for you, so here's an implementation.  It's a fairly easy step to do a wrapper around a stack, too, but Deque is preferred.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public final class BlockingLifoQueue<T> implements BlockingQueue<T>
{
  // we add and remove only from the end of the queue
  private final BlockingDeque<T> deque; 

  public BlockingLifoQueue()
  { deque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<T>(); }

  public boolean add(T e) {
    deque.addLast(e);
    return true;
  }

  public boolean contains(Object o)
  { return deque.contains(o); }

  public int drainTo(Collection<? super T> c)
  { return deque.drainTo(c); }

  public int drainTo(Collection<? super T> c, int maxElements)
  { return deque.drainTo(c,maxElements); }

  public boolean offer(T e)
  { return deque.offerLast(e); }

  public boolean offer(T e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
      throws InterruptedException
  { return deque.offerLast(e,timeout,unit); }

  public T poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
  { return deque.pollLast(timeout, unit); }

  public void put(T e) throws InterruptedException
  { deque.putLast(e); }

  public int remainingCapacity()
  { return deque.size(); }

  public boolean remove(Object o)
  { return deque.remove(o); }

  public T take() throws InterruptedException
  { return deque.takeLast(); }

  public T element()
  {
    if (deque.isEmpty()) { 
      throw new NoSuchElementException("empty stack");
    }

    return deque.pollLast();
  }

  public T peek()
  { return deque.peekLast(); }

  public T poll()
  { return deque.pollLast(); } // deque.peekLast(); } -- fixed typo.

  public T remove()
  {
    if (deque.isEmpty()) { 
      throw new NoSuchElementException("empty stack");
    }

    return deque.pollLast();
  }

  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)
  { 
    for (T e : c) { deque.add(e); }
    return true;
  }

  public void clear()
  { deque.clear();}

  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)
  { return deque.containsAll(c); }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {  return deque.isEmpty(); }

  public Iterator<T> iterator()
  { return deque.descendingIterator(); }

  public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
  { return deque.removeAll(c); }

  public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
  { return deque.retainAll(c); }

  public int size()
  { return deque.size(); }

  public Object[] toArray()
  { return deque.toArray(); }

  public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
  { return deque.toArray(a); }
}
```

Comment: If you really care enough about this, I'd be happy to do an implementation and post it here, but reluctant to do so if the exercise would be in vain...

Comment: I would enjoy and appreciate the implementation.

Comment: If you do an implementation (or wrap an exiting implementation), could you possibly not use a Deque?  I'm actually doing this in android, Deque classes aren't available (prior to the most recently, widely unsupported sdk version).

Comment: Note there is a bug here.
"poll()" should call "pollLast()", not "peekLast()"

Comment: `remainingCapacity` should return the remaining capacity and not the size (i.e., capacity - size)

Answer (score 8):

Similar to what andersoj suggested, however there is the availability of a BlockingDeque.

You can extend the LinkedBlockingDeque class to always pop and push first when offer and removing.

```
public class FIFOBlockingDeque<T> extends LinkedBlockingDeque<T> {

 @Override
 public boolean offer(T t) {
  return super.offerFirst(t);
 }

 @Override
 public T remove() {
  return super.removeFirst();
 }
}
```

Then pass that in as a parameter to the ThreadPoolExecutor (BlockingDeque extends BlockingQueue)

Edit:
To answer your comment question you can instead of inheriting from a Deque, you can use the java.util.Stack supplied.  It is considered legacy, if you are confined to the Java library itself this would be best.

You would instead of offerFirst and removeFirst you can use push and pop.  Of course you would have to implement BlockingQueue and complete that implementation.

Comment: Any suggestion for how to do this without using a Deque class? (I am implementing this in android which lacks Deque classes, prior to the most recent sdk).

Comment: I'm sorry, but the stack supplied by who?

Comment: Deque is a nice solution b/c it has a lot of attention applied to performance... rather than abandoning the idea completely due to Android, you could consider just porting the code; it's available.  If performance isn't really an issue, just using `java.util.Stack` is also an option.  (btw, +1 to John V.)

Comment: Stack is avail at `java.util.Stack` but you'll need to handle the blocking cases in your wrapper...

Comment: Thats a good point andersoj.  To the OP what andersoj just mentioned adds a great deal of complexity that you may want to see if you can get a hold of that implementation for yourself.  Otherwise you would want to read into java.util.concurrent.Lock and Conditions

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct -- doesn't `remove` `removeFirst` by default? Also I believe `add` needs to be overridden to `addFirst`. Check the table in the docs with the "Queue Method" column. Otherwise great solution! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 2):

This would easily be accomplished by using a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) or [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) in which the most recently queued items get highest priority.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a mistake in the @andersoj implementation of the LIFO, in a method of BlockingLifoQueue.

The remove method should be like this:

```
  public T remove()
  {
    if (deque.isEmpty()) { 
      throw new NoSuchElementException("empty stack");
    }

    return deque.pollFirst(); // instead of pollLast()
  }
```

Sorry if I am wrong but It doesn't make sense for me ... to poll the Last in a LIFO.

Answer (score -1):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` constructors accept a `BlockingQueue` that is used to keep the tasks to execute. You will probably need to implement a customized version of `BlockingQueue` to support a LIFO policy.